# Is the Malaria vaccine the first vaccine against a Eukaryote?

Tags: medicine, vaccination, biomedical-engineering

RTS,S or Mosquirix was recently released to the public, offering the first Malaria vaccine. This struck me as particularly important because I don't know of any other vaccine that protects against organisms that aren't prokaryotes or viruses.

Is that accurate? Have there been any other vaccines developed for Eukaryotic organisms? I'm defining vaccine by the CDC definition: *"A preparation that is used to stimulate the body’s immune response against diseases. Vaccines are usually administered through needle injections, but some can be administered by mouth or sprayed into the nose."*

I'm interested in any developed vaccine that offered immunity regardless of relative effectiveness or side effects. Even if it wasn't released to the public.

Alternatively, if anyone has a definitive source indicating that the vaccine is the first of it's kind, that would also answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, in the entry for Giardiasis, there is a commercially available vaccine against Giardiasis that veterinarians can give to cats and dogs.  Giardia is a eukaryote.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giardiasis